# Unable to include cassandra dependency in spring-mvc

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, cassandra, datastax-java-driver, spring-data-cassandra

I am facing issues while trying to include cassandra dependency in my project's pom.xml.

> Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs: [ERROR]
>   Failed to determine Java version for profile doclint-java8-disable @
>   com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-parent:2.1.6,
>   /root/.m2/repository/com/datastax/cassandra/cassandra-driver-parent/2.1.6/cassandra-driver-parent-2.1.6.pom,
>   line 92, column 14

I have tried googling but no success there.

Up till cassandra-driver-core-2.1.2, build gets completed without any error. But when I try building with version 2.1.6 though the build completes successfully the cassandra-driver-parent pom breaks as highlighted above, thus preventing me from importing the required classes.

This is my pom entry:

```
<!-- Cassandra Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
           <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
           <version>2.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The offending profile is declared as this in `com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-parent:2.1.6` :

```
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>doclint-java8-disable</id>
      <activation>
        <jdk>[1.8,)</jdk> <!-- This is line 92 -->
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <javadoc.opts>-Xdoclint:none</javadoc.opts>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```

It seems that your Maven installation is unable to determine which Java version you are running. The syntax is correct and should work (even if it wasn't, you wouldn't be able to do much about it).

You could try disabling the automatic profile activation through the command line:

`-P !doclint-java8-disable`

Comment: Thanks for the info but I am already aware of the root of the issue. I am unable to resolve this with the existing configuration. So I have modified the cassandra-driver-parent-2.1.6 pom by commenting out the erroneous configuration(as highlighted above in the answer) as I am using jdk 1.7 and hence the above entry will not make any difference to me(I assume). As a result the project builds successfully and my pom also compiles without breaking, although I have to test and verify its credibility.